# How do I solve for $y$ in this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y'(t)= 3ty$ where $y(0)=-1$. I have attempted to solve for $y$ by; $$\frac{1}{y}\space dy=3t\space dt$$
$$\int\frac{1}{y}\space dy=\int3t\space dt$$
$$\implies \ln(y)=\frac{3t^{2}}{2} + c$$
$$\implies y=e^{\frac{3t^{2}}{2}} \cdot e^{c}$$
$$\implies-1=e^{c}$$

Hence I have gone wrong somewhere but I am not sure what it is. Can someone explain please?

Comment: You solved the equation ! $y(t)=-\exp(3/2\cdot t^2)$.

Comment: Whenever you have $\ln(y) = f(x) + C$ it's easiest to write this as $y = e^{c+f(x)}=e^ce^{f(x)}$ and let $e^c$ be some other constant say, $A$ to get $ y = A e^{f(x)}$ the boundary condition should now be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(t)= 3ty\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{dy}{dt}=3ty\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$dy=3ty\,dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{1}{y}dy=3t\,dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int \frac{1}{y} \,dy=\int 3t\,dt\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\ln|y|=\frac{3}{2}t^2+C\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=e^{\frac{3}{2}t^2+C}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y=ce^{\frac{3}{2}t^2}$$

$-----$

$$y=ce^{\frac{3}{2}t^2}\Longrightarrow$$
$$-1=ce^{\frac{3}{2}(0)^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-1=ce^0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-1=c(1)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-1=c$$

SO:

$$y=-e^{\frac{3}{2}t^2}$$

Comment: I changed $<=>$ to $\Longleftrightarrow$.  Some day I might begin to suspect that some people don't know that they can learn these things by entering a few search terms into Google, e.g. "LaTeX symbols". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Jan Eerland. From your solution doesn't $e^{c}=-1$ technically, even if one doesn't solve for c. If so, can I still get an exact equation for $y$?

Comment: Mine is completely TRUE and exact, I checked it in Mathematica

Comment: @JanEerland Ok thanks!

Comment: @Jnyeboah93 You're welcome Buddy!

Answer (score 5):

$$
\int\frac{dy} y = \ln|y|+c
$$
\begin{align}
|y| & = e^{3t^2/2} \times\text{a positive constant} \\[10pt]
y & = e^{3t^2/2} \times\text{a constant}
\end{align}
(This handles the case where $y\ne 0$.  If $y=0$ then $\dfrac{dy}y$ doesn't make sense, so you have to check separately that $y=0$ for all $x$ is a solution of the differential equation.  But *this* solution is not that one.)

Comment: REMARK: In the expression $\ln|y|+c$ above one should take $c$ to be piecewise constant, i.e. constant on each of the two intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ separately. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I do not understand your explanation.  Are you saying I cannot find an expression for y and if so why?